# Map some properties from TSource to TDestination without losing old other TDestination object properties values using Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

please I'm working on an **Asp.Net core** project targeted **.Net 5** with **Clean architecture**.

I have this `Entity` in the `Core layer`

**Exam Entity:**

```
public class Exam : IExam
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime ExamDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public TimeSpan ExamTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal DurationByHour { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SchoolSubjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProfId { get; set; }

    public virtual Group                 Group         { get; set; }
    public virtual SchoolSubject         SchoolSubject { get; set; }
    public virtual Prof                  Prof          { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExamMark> ExamMarks     { get; set; }

    public string   CreatedBy    { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn    { get; set; }
    public bool     IsEdited     { get; set; }
    public string   LastEditor   { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastEditDate { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this View Model (For edit) an `Exam` object

**ExamEditVm View model/DTO:**

```
public class ExamEditVm
{
    public int         Id             { get; set; }
    public DateTime    ExamDate       { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan    ExamTime       { get; set; }
    public decimal     DurationByHour { get; set; }
    public string      GroupId        { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups         { get; set; }
}
```

Good, now when a user does some Edits in the **Edit view** and submit the result, another `Edit` **Action result** in **HTTPPOST** will receive the edits as `ExamEditVm` object.
At this point the action should select the **Exam** who should be edited and using `MappingProfile` the action will map the `ExamEditVm` object to selected `Exam` object

**Mapping Profile between `Exam` and `ExamEditVm`:**

```
CreateMap<Exam , ExamEditVm>().ReverseMap();
```

**The HttpPost Edit Action Result:**

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ExamEditVm model)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var exam = await _examRepository.GetByIdAsync( model.Id );
                    exam = _mapper.Map<Exam>( model);
                    exam.WriteEditingAudit( _appUser );
    
                    await _examRepository.UpdateAsync( record : exam );
                    await _uow.CommitAsync();
    
                    return RedirectToAction( nameof( Edit ) , new {model.Id} );
                }
// Some logic
            }
```

**What is exactly the problem?**
The problem is in this line

```
exam = _mapper.Map<Exam>( model);
```

When mapping from `ExamEditVm` to `Exam` the `exam` will lost all not mapped properties values because he got another object value.
So how can I map from `ExamEditVm` to `Exam` and keep the `exam` object old not mapped properties values after mapping using `Automapper` and `MappingProfile` ?

I wish you understand the issue.
So please any solution for his problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing a `exam = _mapper.Map<Exam>(model);` you are actually creating a new `Exam` instance,
with only the data present in the `ExamEditVm model`.

What you want to do, is to apply/map the data from the `ExamEditVm model` object upon the existing `Exam exam` object.
For this, you have to use the `Map` overload passing both the source and target object:

```
_mapper.Map(model, exam);
```